# Pythonic way to eval all octal values in a string as integers

Tags: python, string, eval

So I've got a string that looks like `"012 + 2 - 01 + 24"` for example. I want to be able to quickly (less code) evaluate that expression...

I could use eval() on the string, but I don't want `012` to be represented in octal form (10), I want it to be represented as an int (12).

My solution for this works, but it is not elegant. I am sort of assuming that there is a really good pythonic way to do this.

My solution:

```
#expression is some string that looks like "012 + 2 - 01 + 24"
atomlist = []
for atom in expression.split():
    if "+" not in atom and "-" not in atom:
        atomlist.append(int(atom))
    else:
        atomlist.append(atom)
#print atomlist
evalstring = ""
for atom in atomlist:
    evalstring+=str(atom)    
#print evalstring
num = eval(evalstring)
```

Basically, I tear appart the string, and find numbers in it and turn them into ints, and then I rebuild the string with the ints (essentially removing leading 0's except where 0 is a number on its own).

How can this be done better?

Comment: Side note: `eval('012')` will raise a `SyntaxError` in Python 3 :)

Comment: @RikPoggi: That is a very interesting side note...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd be tempted to use regular expressions to remove the leading zeroes:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\b0+(?!\b)', '', '012 + 2 + 0 - 01 + 204 - 0')
'12 + 2 + 0 - 1 + 204 - 0'
```

This removes zeroes at the start of every number, except when the number consists entirely of zeroes:

- the first `\b` matches a word (token) boundary;
- the `0+` matches one or more consecutive zeroes;
- the `(?!\b)` ([*negative lookahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) inhibits matches where the sequence of zeroes is followed by a token boundary.

One advantage of this approach over `split()`-based alternatives is that it doesn't require spaces in order to work:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\b0+(?!\b)', '', '012+2+0-01+204-0')
'12+2+0-1+204-0'
```

Comment: One more reason why I need to start learning regular expressions

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in one line using lstrip() to strip off any leading zeros:

```
>>> eval("".join(token.lstrip('0') for token in s.split()))
37
```

Comment: Good point!  Not sure there's any easy way around this using my approach.

Comment: +1'd for a good answer anyways. In my particular case the only operations are + and -

Comment: One way to fix the problem would be to use `token.lstrip('0') if token.lstrip('0') else token` or something.  It would still maybe be a little too accepting ("00+" would become "+").

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to do it this way:

```
>>> s = '012 + 2 + 0 - 01 + 204 - 0'
>>> ' '.join(str(int(x)) if x.isdigit() else x for x in s.split())
'12 + 2 + 0 - 1 + 204 - 0'
```

Use `float()` if you want to handle them too :)

Comment: +1 for selfish reasons; this is the first thing I thought of.

Answer (score 1):

`int` does not assume that a leading zero indicates an octal number:

```
In [26]: int('012')
Out[26]: 12
```

Accordingly, you can safely evalute the expression with the following code

```
from operator import add, sub
from collections import deque

def mapper(item, opmap = {'+': add, '-': sub}):
    try: return int(item)
    except ValueError: pass

    return opmap[item]

stack = deque()
# if item filters out empty strings between whitespace sequences
for item in (mapper(item) for item in "012 + 2 - 01 + 24".split(' ') if item):
    if stack and callable(stack[-1]):
        f = stack.pop()
        stack.append(f(stack.pop(), item))
    else: stack.append(item)

print stack.pop()
```

Not a one-liner, but it is safe, because you control all of the functions which can be executed.