# String eval() but ignore leading zeros (octal)

Tags: python, regex

I have a dynamically changing string which is evaluated using eval(). Now for numbers staring with '0' it is represented using octal system. 
Eg. eval('030') = 24

Now there's another thread with a similar issue ([Pythonic way to eval all octal values in a string as integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843033/pythonic-way-to-eval-all-octal-values-in-a-string-as-integers)). The solution in the thread mentions a regular expression

```
re.sub(r'\b0+(?!\b)', '', some_string)
```

Now this works fine in most cases but when I have to evaluate for example '0.08', the aforementioned regex doesn't do the job well because it removes the zero after the decimal (it converst '0.08' tp 0.8' and sin(0.08) to sin(0.8) and so on...) . Given my limited knowledge in regex, I couldn't proceed with solving the issue. So basically, how do I modify the given regex so that it ignores zeroes immediately after decimal points? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at lookahead assertions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: I've tried using negative lookbehind: `re.sub(r'(?<!\.)\b0+(?!\b)', '', a)` and it seems to be working. Does it look right to you guys?

Comment: Yes, but you should write `\B` instead of `(?!\b)` (means the same and looks nicer).

Comment: Also, why are you using `eval()` in the first place? Why not `float()`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I think it's because the string contains an expression that may contain more than a single number.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker Thanks for the \B tip and martineau is correct

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use `eval`? If you only need to convert a string to a number, use `float`:

```
>>> float('0010.001')
10.001
```

Comment: The reason I'm using `eval` is because as @martineau suggested above, the string can have multiple numbers, functions from the math module and some of my own functions and they can all be together in one string. e.g. "0.08 + 030 + sin(pi/6) + ..."

Answer (score 0):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

I've tried using negative lookbehind: `re.sub(r'(?<!\.)\b0+(?!\b)', '', a)` and it seems to be working. Does it look right to you guys? –  Crust3